# Plot multiple density kernels (with area=1) for multiple groups over different time points with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, area, kernel-density, ridgeline-plot

I am trying to plot (in a single graph) two kernel densities (based on two samples with different sample sizes) for two different time points.

Unfortunately, I can't manage to make the area under the curve equal to 1 in order for the densities to be comparable (see for example the following figure at time 1).

Below is an example of my code and the corresponding figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

sim.data1 <- data.frame(
  time = c(rep(1, times = 1000), rep(2, times = 1000)), 
  x = c(rnorm(1000, mean =0 , sd =1 ), rnorm(1000, mean =5 , sd =1 ))
)

sim.data2 <- data.frame(
  time = c(rep(1, times = 300), rep(2, times = 300)), 
  x = c(rnorm(300, mean =0 , sd =1 ), rnorm(300, mean =7 , sd =1 ))
)

ggplot(sim.data1, 
       aes(x = x, y = time, group = time, fill = "red", alpha = 0.5))+           
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 1)+ 
  geom_density_ridges(data = sim.data2, 
                      mapping=aes(x = x, y = time, group=time, fill = "blue"))+
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 1)+ 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: example]

Comment: You've set `scale = 1` for some layers but not others, so it's unsurprising for their areas to differ. You may also want to turn off `theme(legend.position = "none")` & check your legends; I doubt the fill colours are what you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your comments made me realized that indeed I was not plotting what I was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get the figure I wanted.

```
sim.data1 <- data.frame(
time = c(rep(1, times = 1000), rep(2, times = 1000)), 
x = c(rnorm(1000, mean =0 , sd =1 ), rnorm(1000, mean =5 , sd =1 ))
case=rep(1, times = 2*1000)
)

sim.data2 <- data.frame(
time = c(rep(1, times = 300), rep(2, times = 300)), 
x = c(rnorm(300, mean =0 , sd =1 ), rnorm(300, mean =7 , sd =1 )),
case=rep(2, times = 2*300)
)



ggplot(sim.data1, aes(x = x, y =time, group=time,alpha=0.5) ,fill=case)+
geom_density_ridges()+
geom_density_ridges(data= sim.data2, mapping= aes(x = x, y =time,group=time,alpha=0.5,fill=case))+
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[new figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfTTy.png)